# Two Django models with foreign keys in one view

Tags: django, django-models

I'm starting with Django. I have 3 models, a parent class "Cliente" and two child classes, "Persona" and "Empresa".
models.py

```
class Cliente(models.Model):
    idcliente = models.AutoField(unique=True, primary_key=True)
    direccion = models.CharField(max_length=45L, blank=True)
    telefono = models.CharField(max_length=45L, blank=True)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=45L, blank=True) 
    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'Id: %s' % (self.idcliente)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'cliente'

class Empresa(models.Model):
    idcliente = models.ForeignKey('Cliente', db_column='idcliente', primary_key=True)
    cuit = models.CharField(max_length=45L)
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=60L)
    numero_ingresos_brutos = models.CharField(max_length=45L, blank=True) 
    razon_social = models.CharField(max_length=45L, blank=True)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'CUIT: %s - Nombre: %s' % (self.cuit, self.nombre)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'empresa'

class Persona(models.Model):
    idcliente = models.ForeignKey('Cliente', db_column='idcliente', primary_key=True)
    representante_de = models.ForeignKey('Empresa', null=True, db_column='representante_de', blank=True, related_name='representa_a')
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=45L)
    apellido = models.CharField(max_length=45L)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'Id: %s - Nombre completo: %s %s' % (self.idcliente, self.nombre, self.apellido)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'persona'
```

I want to manage a class and its parent in the same view. I want to add, edit and delete "Cliente" and "Persona"/"Cliente" in the same form. Can you help me?

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stackoverflow! This Q&A site's main language is english, would it be possible for you to translate your question, please?

Comment: When you have `ForeignKey` with `primary_key=True`, consider `OneToOneField` instead.

Comment: Changing ForeignKey to OneToOneField solve it. thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a good example in the Documentation [Here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/forms/modelforms/).

I wrote this based on the documentation, so it is untested.

```
def manage_books(request, client_id):
    client = Cliente.objects.get(pk=client_id)
    EmpresaInlineFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Cliente, Empresa)
    if request.method == "POST":
        formset = EmpresaInlineFormSet(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=author)
        if formset.is_valid():
            formset.save()
            # Do something. Should generally end with a redirect. For example:
            return HttpResponseRedirect(client.get_absolute_url())
    else:
        formset = EmpresaInlineFormSet(instance=client)
    return render_to_response("manage_empresa.html", {
        "formset": formset,
    })
```